# coredump in string assignment

Tags: c++, coredump

I want to know the scenario where it is possible to get the segmentation fault when we try to do getline() function to read a line from a file

Eg:

```
ifstream h("one.txt");
string s;
getline(h,s); //what assignment to 'h' can lead to segmentaion fault here (or) 
              //is it possible to get the segmentation fault based on the content of the file?
```

I need the answer for this

Comment: The code that ran before this.  And corrupted the heap.

Comment: Almost certainly heap corruption as Hans says. The getline allocates memory for the ifstream read buffer and allocates memory for the string, so if the heap is corrupted it will segfault.

Comment: "It will segfault". No. It will segfault _if you are lucky_. The correct phrase is "if the heap is corrupted you have UB and anything can happen".

Comment: Have you seen this code produce a seg fault, or are you asking about hypothetical circumstances in which it might do so?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd probably get undefined behavior (which *might* manifest as a seg fault) if "one.txt" contains a line longer than can fit into memory.  The number of characters read by `getline()` is constrained by the `max_size()` of the `string` object, but that can be pretty big.

Answer (score -1):

> is it possible to get the segmentation fault based on the content of
>   the file?

It's hardly possible, assuming your code has no **Undefined Behaviour** - otherwise everything is possible including segmentation fault. Standard C++ Library is used by many people. It is well tested and does error checking of input values.

Comment: -1: It's absolutely possible. The standard library functions won't contain the bugs that cause UB, but your _own_ bugs causing UB can certainly affect the standard library functions.

Comment: I assume my code has no UB. In this case this code will hardly crash because of some special content of the file.